# Straight Insertion, how to count swaps?

Tags: algorithm, count, insertion

This may sound stupid, but i need a confirmation. 
For example we have an integer array:

```
 [4 2 1 3]
```

So when the algorithm kicks in, it should work like that

```
 1. [2 4 1 3] 
 2. [1 2 4 3]  
 3. [1 2 3 4]
```

Can someone help me count the swaps for each step? 
From my perspective its probably 1) 1 swap, 2) 2 swaps, 3) 1 swap. Is this correct? thanks

Algorithm:

```
for(i=1; i<N; i++)
{
    x = p[i];
    j = i -1;
    while(x<p[j] && j>=0)
    {
        p[j+1] = p[j];
        j = j-1;
    }
    p[j+1] = x;
}
```

Comment: Which algorithm kicks in? insertion sort?

Comment: straight insertion is what my teacher calling it. i guess its the insertion sort. i included the algorithm in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this algorithm is a new one (Its not exactly insertion sort, but very near to it)

Now, number of swaps that this algorithm does is `0`. It is just doing the assignments, no swaps at all. If you are calling number of assignments inside `while` as `swaps`, then yes, you are correct. And if you want to check that, just edit your code to this:

```
for(i=1; i<N; i++)
{
    x = p[i];
    j = i -1;
    int n=0;
    while(x<p[j] && j>=0)
    {
        p[j+1] = p[j];
        j = j-1;
        n++;
    }
    //output n, looks like c so
    printf("%d\n",n);
    p[j+1] = x;
}
```